# What is the exact role of the DEPENDS in Makefile?

Tags: makefile, lua, openwrt, luci

Here is a sample of my Makefile.

```
define Package/luci-app-myapp
   SECTION:=luci
   CATEGORY:=LuCI
   SUBMENU:=3. Applications
   TITLE:=GUI for myapp package
   PKGARCH:=all
   DEPENDS:=+myapp
endef
```

What is the exact role of the DEPENDS in this Makefile?
And what elements can be the value of the DEPENDS?

Comment: This isn't a makefile question per se.  All this does from a  make standpoint is define a variable named `Package/luci-app-myapp` which has the value above.  Presumably there is some makefile framework around this which will work with this variable value (most likely via `eval` or similar).  However it's up to that framework to decide what `DEPENDS` is and what it does.  We can infer that it defines a set of targets that this target depends on (that need to be built before this target can be built).  But it's just a guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DEPENDS is basically a variable. In openwrt this variable is used to define dependency between the packages.
Detailed use of this variable is documented in openwrt [link](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/devel/dependencies)

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thank you!!